# Not found error when downloading large file [APACHE]

Tags: apache, limit, large-files

When I want download a large file (example 8GB) from my server I got not found error. 
I don't using apache modules such as DAV or modbwlimit. 

Also I didn't set max limitmaxrequestboy on my httpd.conf

I'm using cPanel , RHEL 6 , Apache 2.4

**How Can i fix this problem and able to download large file like +10GB **

Thanks

Comment: Can you download smoll files(example 1GB)?

Comment: Yes , I can. thanks for your replay

Comment: Are files larger than 2GB un-downloadable?

Comment: Yes , it's because of some modules in apache. I rebuilt webserver without additional modules. but i don't know which modules made that problem.

Comment: At apache 2.0 , compile options "-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE" and "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" are necessary to make apache to be possible to handle large, larger than 2GB, files. WebLogic Web server plug-in must be compiled with same compile options.  I'm not sure that this relates your problem, but something is common because its border exists on 31bit-limit( 2^31 = 2G ).